# Affixed/sticky header jumping

Tags: header, sticky

I'm trying to fix up a client's Wordpress website. When scrolling down or back up, the site jumps when the sticky header is activated. The theme used is "Enigma". This is the site in question: http://fm6.co.uk/services/.

Comment: When the header is made to be sticky (fixed), it's no longer displacing the content of the page. So maybe making that displacement still be there would work? (You could maybe try adding a margin/padding (equal to the header's height) to the top of the page when the header is sticky.)

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try!

Comment: Okay, I tried doing that, but it didn't work; the page still jumps. I just realized that the stickyness (ha, probably not the right word) only seems to be applying to the navigation menu itself, and not the entire header, so I think it needs to be modified to include the entire header container. As an amateur, I am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to change that.

Comment: The only other element inside the `<div>` that contains the `#enigma_nav_top` (this is the header element, right?) is empty, though. (But you could add an ID to that `<div>` and then target your added ID with your CSS or JavaScript.)

Comment: I'm actually having a little trouble visualizing what the sticky header is meant to do; do you have a particular site you're trying to replicate..? I'm wondering if the header itself is meant to *jump*; it seems a little jarring. Unless you're only trying to make the navigation part be stickied? (If you want the whole header to always be on top of the screen, you could just make it always be `position: fixed`.)

Comment: I appreciate your help. I can't say that there's a particular site I'm trying to copy. I just want the logo, nav buttons, contact info, and social media icons to stay in the same place when scrolling down. Right now, they seem to jump once you scroll down to about where the top of the navigation buttons are. It's just not a smooth transition. I might just get rid of the sticky part altogether to save the headache.

Comment: Headaches might be avoidable even while still getting the sticky effect you're looking for (..but that's not guaranteed!) :) -- in this video: https://streamable.com/kbi3f ..I've made the header element simply be `position: fixed; width: 100%; background: white;`, and added a `254px` margin to the top of the actual content of the page. It's definitely not perfect (it fails miserably when the screen is relatively small, for example: http://i.cubeupload.com/GNp04L.png, and the nav doesn't line up with the content), but maybe it helps demonstrate a concept for a possible solution.